# What are the benefits of being outspoken?

Tags: software-industry, colleagues

I'm a Software Engineer working in an Outsourcing company in Asia. This morning, my boss was talking to me in a private meeting about a coworker:

*"I like his style, civilized, just like a westerner[EU/US]...What you actually did matters little, as long as everybody think that you did it."*

By my standard (and any other coworkers') he is a 'big mouth'. Nobody except my boss likes him.

By "big mouth" I was referring to overly boastful. He also takes credit for other peoples work.

I'm wondering if being a big mouth really gains you that much of an advantage in business? Should I change my style to be similar to his?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'm a Software Engineer working in an Outsourcing company in Asia.

Comment: It appears that your boss likes your co-worker due to their western tendencies and the fact they are extroverted. This may be because they are different from everyone else and match the personality of other upper management personnel.

Comment: *What you actually did matters little, as long as everybody think that you did it.* Nice boss to work for.

Comment: @JanDoggen not a nice boss, but accurate advice nonetheless.

Comment: it's a cultural thing in many places, Westerners tend to be noisier (not always with any justification).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Self-promotion to some extent is vital.  There is a vast difference, however, between being a shameless self-promoter, or "Big mouth" as you put it, and effectively selling yourself.

Nobody is going to see the value you bring to the company unless you tell them.  The idea that one's work speaks for itself is naïve.  A mediocre worker who promotes himself will always pass the dedicated, but quiet worker.  This is not right.  This is not fair.  It is, however, how things work.

That said, there is a way to self-promote without being phony or a big-mouth.

You should change your style, but change it to one that legitimately promotes your worth without taking credit for the work of others.  Put everything in the context of "We had a problem", "I noticed the problem and took (X) action", and "When I did that, this was the result".  Quantify everything.  Also, act quickly when you achieve something, as this will also prevent work-thieves from being able to take advantage of you.

There is a book titled "Brag, how to toot your own horn without blowing it", which I would recommend that goes into some detail on the subject.

Comment: "This is not right. This is not fair. It is, however, how things work." - I felt like you said "Just go with it bruh!", I'm a quiet worker and I see how shitty people think I am because I don't "brag" about it, I think I should mention what I do once in a while, thanks for the answer Richard +1

Comment: @Mr.Derpinthoughton  I ***was*** a quiet worker at one time.  Guess who got laid off and had to be replaced by 3 people because they didn't know how much he did?  That's when I learned my lesson.  Please, do let your employers know what you do, your coworkers might not represent you accurately.

Comment: If you don;t take credit for what you do, then you are just enabling the "big  mouths' to take the credit. You can't steal credit from someone who is already known to be the person who did the task.

Comment: I'm starting to feel the effects of not letting my employer know what I'm doing and how much I'm doing affect me, I'm gonna read that book you mentioned "Brag, how to toot your own horn without blowing it"

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be introverted when contrasted to your co-worker, lets explore the issues with this:

In the modern age where being an extrovert is seen as desirable and seems to open more doors especially in sales and the entertainment industry being an introvert definitely has its disadvantages. Because they are private in nature and guard their thoughts and emotions it can be difficult for them to form friendships with many people, this maybe partly because they are not as socialized as other people having not learnt the necessary skills to be a social butterfly due to being used to having their own personal space and distance. Another disadvantage is the ability to be outspoken or speak their mind, this can be in the workplace situation or in a social setting making them feeling isolated and cause them to withdraw even further than they have already. Though being introvert or enjoying your own company isn't usually the problem, it is the perception of being an introvert which can make people think it is a social deficiency to not want to be constantly around others, this in itself can itself cause people to doubt your character and perceive you differently to other people.

Usually people aren't a complete introvert or even completely extroverted, they usually are a balanced between the two depending on how they feel, how their day pans out or maybe the environment they are currently in requires them to be more one than the other. Having a mixture of both is necessary as balance is more beneficial than extremes.

Hopefully you can spot the parallels between the issues surrounding being introverted and the behaviours that management expect from high-preforming employees that they consider to be suitable for management.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to become comfortable with taking credit for things that are legitimately your achievements... something I have to admit I am still working on after all these years.

And to be positive about tracking new challenges. And to be outgoing. Or to learn to fake these well enough to not come across as timid or unwilling.

That isn't "boasting", it's just not hiding your light under a basket.

What you should **not** be doing is claiming work done by others, or promising more than you can deliver.